# iOS: block capture a value

Tags: objective-c

```
-(xFuncTest)funcX {
    int __block inner = 0;
    xFuncTest blockTest = ^(int mark) {
        return inner += mark;
    };
    return blockTest;
}

xFuncTest func = [self funcX];
NSLog(@"%d",func(1));
NSLog(@"%d",func(1));
NSLog(@"%d",func(1));
```

the result is 1 , 2, 3. but I am confused. because every time the method run. inner has been stetted to 1. why it will remember last value?

Comment: Hi - it is same block you run every time. Associated with the block is an int called inner and initially set to 0. So the first time you run it with arg 1, you add 1 to inner and it becomes and prints 1. The next time you run it, again with arg 1, you add 1 to it and it becomes 2 and prints 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with a bit more detail.

```
#import "Block.h"

typedef int ( ^ xFuncTest )( int );

@implementation Block

- ( xFuncTest ) funcX
{
    int __block inner = 0;

    xFuncTest blockTest = ^ ( int mark )
    {
        NSLog ( @"\tInside block, inner is %p value %d", & inner, inner );
        NSLog ( @"\t\tWill add %d to it", mark );

        return inner += mark;
    };

    return blockTest;
}

- ( void ) test
{
    xFuncTest func = [self funcX];

    for ( int arg = 1; arg < 5; arg ++ )
    {
        NSLog ( @"Calling %p with arg %d", func, arg );
        NSLog ( @"Result %d", func ( arg ) );
        NSLog ( @"\n" );
    }

    // This resets it - when you create a new block
    func = [self funcX];

    NSLog ( @"Now I have a new block %p, calling it with arg 20", func );
    func ( 20 );
}

@end
```

Note specifically that each time the block is called I print out the address (and value) of the inner integer. I also print out the address of the block.

Also note that later on I create a *new* block. This will reset the inner int, in fact, it creates a totally new one as the output will show.

Now calling that test function produces the following output.

```
2020-10-27 12:52:30.397754+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Hello, World!
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398181+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Calling 0x100406350 with arg 1
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398218+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]   Inside block, inner is 0x1004063d8 value 0
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398244+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]       Will add 1 to it
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398266+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Result 1
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398286+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] 
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398308+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Calling 0x100406350 with arg 2
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398329+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]   Inside block, inner is 0x1004063d8 value 1
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398350+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]       Will add 2 to it
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398416+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Result 3
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398481+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] 
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398530+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Calling 0x100406350 with arg 3
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398556+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]   Inside block, inner is 0x1004063d8 value 3
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398578+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]       Will add 3 to it
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398620+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Result 6
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398642+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] 
2020-10-27 12:52:30.398689+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Calling 0x100406350 with arg 4
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403090+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]   Inside block, inner is 0x1004063d8 value 6
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403127+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]       Will add 4 to it
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403150+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Result 10
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403172+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] 
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403235+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881] Now I have a new block 0x102804090, calling it with arg 20
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403281+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]   Inside block, inner is 0x1028040d8 value 0
2020-10-27 12:52:30.403309+0200 BlockIllustration[1536:55881]       Will add 20 to it
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Note that the inner integer uses the same address - it is the same and it will stay that way and only go away when the block itself goes out of scope. This is because it was marked as a `__block` variable and is tied to that block.

However, whenever you create a *new* block you also get a new inner integer together with it. This what the latter part of the test tries to illustrate.

HIH

Comment: it is easy to understand. Thank you.